# How can I save and restore a graph that uses Tensorflow Hub Module

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am looking for a working example where I use a TF Hub image module, finetune it for a custom task, backpropagate to hub module as well. Then save this resulting model and reload it for evaluation.

I have looked at https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py but I don't think it trains the module.

Comment: have you managed to get it to work? If so, how ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I was able to make it work. However, I think the document has evolved quite a bit since I posted my question. Here are more details: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just works as usual when restoring a model from a checkpoint.

- If your model is being restored from a checkpoint then the module variables will also be restored from it (and not loaded from the original module).
- The only time the module variables are set to the original values is when their initializers is run.